# Как сделать элемент активным после нажатия?

Tags: html, css

Я сделал слайдер. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии, например, на слово "Web design", оно становилось другого цвета. 
Именно не при наведении, а уже после нажатия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно с помощью js

Comment: @goodalien1125, а зачем?! Зачем совать везде js?

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, мне кажется с его помощью реализовать проще..

Comment: добавь пример разметки своего слайдера

Answer (score 2):

Если без помощи js, то на css это осуществляется, методом спрятанного чекбокса, обернутого в **label**

Соответственно в css для состояния **checked** меняете стиль

**UPD**

html

```
<input id="tabl1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked=""> 
<label for="tabl1">your html</label>
```

css

```
.tabs > label:hover {
  some-style
}

.tabs > input:checked + label {
  other-style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   a:link {
    color: #0000d0; /* Цвет ссылок */
   }
   a:visited {
    color: #900060; /* Цвет посещенных ссылок */
   }
   a:active {
    color: #f00; /* Цвет активной ссылки */ 
   }
```

[док.](http://htmlbook.ru/css/active)

Comment: Я имею ввиду конкретный момент времени. То есть при нажатии на "Web design" он становился бы красного цвета, а при нажатии на другой элемент, "Web design" становился бы опять белого цвета. И так для каждого элемента

Comment: Хех, не помогли хаки с css :)

Comment: @Levelleor, какие хаки?!

Comment: @Elena Semenchenko, ну вы так грозно настаивали что js не нужно впутывать что это даже от части смешно.

Comment: @Levelleor, смешно не знать основ css и вставлять js туда где он не нужен!!! Засоряя страницу!

Comment: @Elena Semenchenko, алье, основы все знают, я думаю. Но вы не забывайте что в данном случае основы как обычно не проканали.

Comment: @Levelleor, проканали бы, если б в примере был target